# nodejs child process - Error: spawn node ENOENT

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm using this code to try spawn a child process that needs to run a script.

```
const child = require('child_process').spawn;
const path = require('path');
const script = path.format({dir: __dirname, base: 'myscript.js'});

    child('node', [script], {
        cwd: __dirname,
        env: {
            TEST_USERNAME: 'myuser',
            TEST_PASSWORD: 'mypassword'
        }
    }).on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I'm getting this error when I try to run my `index.js` script

```
Error: spawn node ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:276:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn node',
  path: 'node',
  spawnargs: [ '/Users/dev/Desktop/cli-training/demo.js' ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to run the child script after that `inquirer.js` have prompted some questions to the user. Can be this the problem?I've noticed that the child process will be not executed. Inside my child script I have this code

```
const { IgApiClient } = require('instagram-private-api');
const chalk = require('chalk');

console.log(chalk.magenta('Starting child script'));

const ig = new IgApiClient();

console.log(process.argv);
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: My guess is, the `script` is not returning the correct file path to `myscript.js`. Can you do a `console.log` on `script`?

Comment: @fortunee I was thinking that the error was with the `env` objectI'm passing to it. I've done a `console.log` on the script like you've suggested and it will return the correct path where the script is located. Maybe I need to add the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node` also into the child script?

Comment: I would agree with @fortunee. There might be the case that path representation can be different on different platforms. For example / should be replaced with \ and/or you need to specify full path to it.

Comment: @Reborn I've done some debug, it's not a path related problem but it's related to the env object I'm trying to pass to the script. In the documentation it's written that the env need a key value pair but maybe I'm passing it in the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute the node binary in a child-process, it s better to refer to its full path, you can find it with `process.execPath`

this should fix your problem

```
child(process.execPath, [script], {
        cwd: __dirname,
        env: {
            TEST_USERNAME: 'myuser',
            TEST_PASSWORD: 'mypassword'
        }
    }).on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: This solution solved the problem, thank you.